# CD/DVD Creator is not functional

Tags: 18.04, burning, cd-drive

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3, and the CD/DVD Creator tool seems to be nonfuctional, and potentially even missing. Here are the symptoms:

1. I insert a blank CD into the optical drive. Nothing pops up: no Nautilus, no application manager. 18.04 documentation ([here](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/files-disc-write.html.en)) suggests that a "Blank CD/DVD-R Disc notification" should appear at the bottom of the screen, but none does.
2. I launch Nautilus and the CD is there in the left sidebar as "Blank CD-RW Disc". I double click it. It just opens it like it's a normal empty directory, no "CD/DVD Creator" option or window comes up. That's it.

Here is what I have tried to fix the issue, and what I have checked for the issue:

- Bookmarking the blank CD in Nautilus makes "CD/DVD Creator" show up in the left hand pane of Nautilus. Clicking on it just displays the CD like a normal empty directory again. I can drag files in there but they don't get written to the disc (I cannot hear the optical drive run, and ejecting and re-inserting shows it's empty). There is no "Write to Disc" or "burn" button to click, as the linked documentation suggests there should be.
- Selecting files, right clicking, and choosing "Move to...", and then selecting the blank CD causes the name of the CD to change to "CD/DVD Creator", but again, the files do not get written to disc and there is no "Write to Disc" or "Burn" button available.
- Adding the user to the "cdrom" group and restarting.
- Checking that the specific optical drive model is capable of writing to CD-RWs. It is.
- Tried a CD-R instead of a CD-RW. Same issue. Also double checked that the specific CDs I have can store the type/size of files I am attempting to burn to them. They can.
- Bought an external CD drive in case the built-in optical drive on my Lenovo is dead. Same issue.
- Tried a whole separate computer with 18.04.3 (a system76 instead of the Lenovo). Same issue.
- I attempted to add CD/DVD Creator as the default handling when a blank CD is inserted through the "Removable Media"->"Other Media" settings menu. However, CD/DVD Creator is nowhere to be found as an option to launch. Also, choosing the "Ask what to do" option does nothing; when I insert a blank CD, nothing pops up asking what to do.

This is a significant issue for me. Unfortunately, because of strict security protocol, this computer cannot be connected to the internet, and what tools can be installed on it is closely controlled. This makes it difficult to install third party disc burning software or tools to diagnose what's going on with CD/DVD Creator. I did attempt to install Brasero from a flash drive, but it failed repeatedly due to to missing dependencies and I eventually gave up. I also cannot use different media (like a flash drive) to store the files I need for security reasons.

So, was CD/DVD Creator removed for Ubuntu and the docs have not caught up? Is this a known bug? Are there known workarounds for this, or could someone suggest a reliable CD burning application other than Brasero that might be less trouble to install via USB?

Comment: Read another question before about burning ISOs and it was mention that brasero had to be installed on recent versions.  What you might need is a snap version of a burning program, suppose to contain all dependencies.  Google or https://alternativeto.net/ should find different types, but don't know if any are snaps.  Ubuntu should have a snap store and/or snaps be listed in ubuntu's software store.  If possible and have space on computer, could dual boot with 16.04 or 14.04, they both should have it installed.